# Configuration Application to use Syncfusion ReportViewer Conditional Formatting

Tags: report, reportviewer, conditional-formatting, syncfusion

I am using ASP.NET MVC using Syncfusion to create report and want to create report viewer with conditional formating like this:

[image]

So please help me to configure the things needed to create the same.

Howmany files or dll I have to give as reference in my application to do this and how to create conditional formatting?'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @D.Dharanidharan can you please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following getting-started tutorial that how can integrate the Syncfusion Report Viewer with ASP.NET MVC Environment.

https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/reportviewer/getting-started

Below article will helps you to create conditional formatting reports.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252080(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Sir I have already go through this link but not getting the proper solution how to create conditional formatting report. Is there any demo available to get as per requirement like above question that will be nice sir using stored procedure!